# Что значит слово CALLBACK в функции WndProc ?

Tags: winapi, callback, c++

Что значит слово CALLBACK в функции WndProc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cоглашение о вызовах (calling convention) - определение порядка размещения параметров, передаваемых при вызове функций и возврате в вызывающую программу, в стеке и извлечения из стека

Comment: @AlekseyOk, т.е. это ни имеет ничего общего с  обратным вызовом?

Comment: ну как сказать, имеет.

Comment: имеет.
CALLBACK используется в MS компилляторах для указания того факта, что вызывающая сторона (обычно) будет очищать стек.

P.S. Собственно, это макрос, раскрывающийся в __stdcall

P.P.S. http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/159935.1

Answer (score 3):

Нужно понимать, что есть такой способ разделения кода, как callback функции. Заключается в том, что некоторый код знает только адрес функции, которую он должен вызвать, если наступит какое то событие. А сам код ему не важен. Это позволяет разделять логику. Например, некий код может печатать список компьютеров в локальной сети. А для печати каждого элемента он вызывает функцию. Используя этот код, нужно передать ему как параметр адрес функции, которая собственно будет печатать. А как эта функция будет печатать, это ее дело. Она может вообще считать кол-во символов.

В данном случае (по тексту вопроса) оконную функцию вызывает операционная система, когда ей нужно передать что то приложению.

по поводу слова `CALLBACK` - это просто define (WinDef.h), который определен по разному, в зависимости от опций компиляции.

```
#ifdef _MAC
#define CALLBACK    PASCAL
#endif
#elif (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
#define CALLBACK    __stdcall
#else
#define CALLBACK
#endif
```

Из этого видно, что обычно `CALLBACK` равно `__stdcall`.